# Multiple inheritance: using a member function of a private base

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance

Here is my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
    public:
        virtual void f() = 0;
};
class B {
    public:
        void f() {cout << "Hello world!" << endl;};
};
class C : public A, private B {
    public:
        using B::f; // I want to use B::f as my implementation of A::f
};


int main() {
    C c; // error: C is abstract because f is pure virtual
    c.f(); 
}
```

Now so far I have found two workarounds:

1. Define a function f in class C that just calls B::f. But this is tedious and not so clean (especially when doing that for a bunch of functions)
2. B inherits from A and C inherits from B (all public). For me it does not represents well the design. In particular, B is NOT a A, and I don't want B to depend on A.

Can you think of any other possibility ?

Comment: If `B` is not an `A`, why does it have to implement `A::f`?

Comment: You can achieve your goal by deriving from `A` virtually, but that would bring its own set of problems.

Comment: It is called a [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche, it's handy to be able to implement specific actions with a small reusable class.

Comment: I don't understand why `using B::f;` is less tedious than `void f() { B::f(); }`. If it were me I wouldn't use the same name for both functions anyway, it would be `B::f_impl`.

Comment: IMHO if 2 classes, A and B, have a methos with the same name (I guess same name, f(), implies same or similar purpose), they should probably have a common base. In general, if you have trouble to impement something inheritance-related, you should consider reviewing the architecture.

Comment: if you are after diamond-type inheritance, Scott Meyers' book is a very good source of information

Comment: @MarkRansom Imagine a more complex case, `using B::f;` vs. `void f(X1 x1, const X2 &x2, X3 *x3) { B::f(std::move(x1), x2, x3); }`

Comment: @YuliaV, in this case `A` could be an interface with many methods and `B` could be a helper that provides a common implementation of one very small subset. A common base wouldn't be practical.

Comment: @Angew So, what about `template<class... Args> auto f(Args&&... args) -> decltype(B::f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) { /*..*/ }`

Comment: @DyP Assuming your compiler supports variadic templates, that would work of course. It's still a bit more wordy than `using B::f;`, but one could easily write a macro for it. I think this would actually be the best solution; an optimiser worthy of that name should eventually skip the helper function anyway. I think you should turn this to an answer.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. @DyP This is indeed another possibility, but more complicated for most cases than just writing the proxy function (solution 2.) When reading throught the class interface, it will be a double-take to understand why this is here and what is the purpose.

Comment: @Angrew I'm always reluctant at using a macro if there is another acceptable solution. I still prefer solution 2.

Comment: @MarkRansom Handy maybe, but i'd rather keep the need to explicitly specify the relationship `A`→`B`, or to proxy `f`, than save a few characters.

Comment: Solution 1. I mean I prefer solution 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The using declaration is adding the `B::f` function into the class scope for the purpose of lookup, but the function is still `B::f`, not `C::f`. You can define the implementation in the derived type and forward to the `B::f` implementation or else you would have to change your inheritance hierarchy so that both `B` and `C` inherit (virtually) from `A`.

```
void C::f() { B::f(); }   // simple forwarding implementation
```